# Why does my compiler have a memory problem with a vector of c string type?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

Why can't I create a vector of c string time. When I create one my compiler throws a memory problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char[32]> buffVector;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, that isn't a C string; it's an array of `char`. Second, review the requirements of the underlying element type containable in a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then think about which of them `char[32]` does *not* comply with. (hint: what does [*copy-assignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) mean ?)

Comment: What do you mean by "compiler throws a memory problem"??  Describe the symptom (error message, or whatever).   Don't rely on people to guess if you don't explain it properly.

Answer (score 4):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector:

> `T` must meet the requirements of [*CopyAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) and [*CopyConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible).

The reason you can't use `vector<char[32]>` is  that `char[32]` is neither [CopyAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) nor [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible).

You can't use:

```
char a[32];
char b[32];

a = b;           // Can't assign an array to another.
char c[32] = b;  // Can't initialize an array using another.
```

Fortunately, there is an easy work around. You can wrap the array in a `struct` and use a `vector` of the `struct` instead.

```
struct foo { char array[32]; };
std::vector<foo> v; // OK.
```